# NSDateFormatter.dateFromString in for loop, with @try to handle invalid format

Tags: ios, objective-c, try-catch, nsdateformatter

I am trying to parse date string from dictionary, with the possibility of invalid format. So I loop the dictionary and try to parse them with DateFormatter.dateFromString in the @try @catch.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];

for(NSDictionary *mainSettlementData in mainSettlementDataList){

    NSString *dateString = [mainSettlementData objectForKey:@"settlementDate1"];
    if(dateString){
        NSLog(@"1");
        NSLog(@"dateString = %@", dateString);
        @try{
            NSDate *settlementDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
            NSLog(@"converted NSDate = %@", settlementDate);
        }
        @catch(NSException *e){
            NSLog(@"Error parsing settlementDate : %@", e.description);
        }
        NSLog(@"2");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"3");
    }
}
NSLog(@"Finish Loading Date");
```

The result from NSLog is good until the input's format is invalid

```
2015-08-01 17:42:37.080 TrinityBackOffice[878:132472] 1
2015-08-01 17:42:37.081 TrinityBackOffice[878:132472] dateString = 05-Aug-2014
2015-08-01 17:42:37.084 TrinityBackOffice[878:132472] converted NSDate = 2014-08-04 17:00:00 +0000
2015-08-01 17:42:37.084 TrinityBackOffice[878:132472] 2
2015-08-01 17:42:37.084 TrinityBackOffice[878:132472] 1
2015-08-01 17:42:37.084 TrinityBackOffice[878:132472] dateString = 02-Oct-2012
2015-08-01 17:42:37.084 TrinityBackOffice[878:132472] converted NSDate = 2012-10-01 17:00:00 +0000
2015-08-01 17:42:37.085 TrinityBackOffice[878:132472] 2
2015-08-01 17:42:37.085 TrinityBackOffice[878:132472] 1
2015-08-01 17:42:37.085 TrinityBackOffice[878:132472] dateString = 05-Aug-2014
2015-08-01 17:42:37.085 TrinityBackOffice[878:132472] converted NSDate = 2014-08-04 17:00:00 +0000
2015-08-01 17:42:37.085 TrinityBackOffice[878:132472] 2
2015-08-01 17:42:37.085 TrinityBackOffice[878:132472] 1
2015-08-01 17:42:37.086 TrinityBackOffice[878:132472] dateString = 05-Aug-2014
2015-08-01 17:42:37.086 TrinityBackOffice[878:132472] converted NSDate = 2014-08-04 17:00:00 +0000
2015-08-01 17:42:37.086 TrinityBackOffice[878:132472] 2
2015-08-01 17:42:37.087 TrinityBackOffice[878:132472] 1
2015-08-01 17:42:37.088 TrinityBackOffice[878:132472] dateString = <null>
2015-08-01 17:42:37.088 TrinityBackOffice[878:132472] -[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xbabb48
2015-08-01 17:42:37.088 TrinityBackOffice[878:132472] Error parsing settlementDate : -[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xbabb48
2015-08-01 17:42:37.089 TrinityBackOffice[878:132472] 2
2015-08-01 17:42:37.089 TrinityBackOffice[878:132472] 1
2015-08-01 17:42:37.089 TrinityBackOffice[878:132472] dateString = 02-Oct-2012
```

Then the logging stop, and the app freeze. The last log NSLog(@"Finish Loading Date"); never print out. Please note that I do it in viewDidLoad of the first ViewController of the app, so the app freeze at the splash screen page.

Please also note that if there is no invalid date string in the dictionary, the app works fine. If I remove the line

```
NSDate *settlementDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

the app also works fine.

Please help, thanks!

PS. The data source is here if you would like to have.

```
NSData *data =
[@"{\"asOfDate\":\"23-Jul-2015\",\"portfolioData\":[{\"costValue\":11464.614,\"accountID\":\"99-91418-4\",\"mktValue\":10800,\"unrealizedAmt\":-664.61},{\"costValue\":0,\"accountID\":\"999-091418-0-3\",\"mktValue\":0,\"unrealizedAmt\":46600}],\"settlementData\":[{\"settlementDate2\":null,\"accountID\":\"99-00427-1\",\"netAmount3\":0,\"bankSym\":\"BBL\",\"settlementDate1\":\"05-Aug-2014\",\"netAmount1\":0,\"netAmount2\":0,\"bankAcc\":\"1310689722\",\"settlementDate3\":null},{\"settlementDate2\":\"05-Aug-2014\",\"accountID\":\"99-00427-4\",\"netAmount3\":3075.06,\"bankSym\":\"BBL\",\"settlementDate1\":\"02-Oct-2012\",\"netAmount1\":-86858.6,\"netAmount2\":-13096.74,\"bankAcc\":\"1310689722\",\"settlementDate3\":\"07-Aug-2014\"},{\"settlementDate2\":\"06-Aug-2014\",\"accountID\":\"99-00427-0\",\"netAmount3\":-226381.6,\"bankSym\":\"BBL\",\"settlementDate1\":\"05-Aug-2014\",\"netAmount1\":-442746.3,\"netAmount2\":323452.94,\"bankAcc\":\"1310689722\",\"settlementDate3\":\"07-Aug-2014\"},{\"settlementDate2\":\"06-Aug-2014\",\"accountID\":\"99-00427-0\",\"netAmount3\":-226381.6,\"bankSym\":\"BBL\",\"settlementDate1\":\"05-Aug-2014\",\"netAmount1\":-442746.3,\"netAmount2\":323452.94,\"bankAcc\":\"1310689722\",\"settlementDate3\":\"07-Aug-2014\"},{\"settlementDate2\":null,\"accountID\":\"99-00427-1\",\"netAmount3\":0,\"bankSym\":\"BBL\",\"settlementDate1\":null,\"netAmount1\":0,\"netAmount2\":0,\"bankAcc\":\"1310689722\",\"settlementDate3\":null},{\"settlementDate2\":\"05-Aug-2014\",\"accountID\":\"99-00427-4\",\"netAmount3\":3075.06,\"bankSym\":\"BBL\",\"settlementDate1\":\"02-Oct-2012\",\"netAmount1\":-86858.6,\"netAmount2\":-13096.74,\"bankAcc\":\"1310689722\",\"settlementDate3\":\"07-Aug-2014\"}],\"transactionStatus\":[]}" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSError *myError = nil;
NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];
NSArray *mainSettlementDataList = [responseDictionary objectForKey:@"settlementData"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your data in `settlementDate1` return null value so you check condition date is not null then set Date formate.

You try this code :

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];

        for(NSDictionary *mainSettlementData in mainSettlementDataList){

            NSString *dateString = [mainSettlementData objectForKey:@"settlementDate1"];
            if(![dateString isEqual:[NSNull null]]){
                NSLog(@"1");
                NSLog(@"dateString = %@", dateString);

                NSDate *settlementDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
                NSLog(@"converted NSDate = %@", settlementDate);
            }
            else{
                NSLog(@"3");
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"Finish Loading Date");
```

or use this condition to check null value

```
if(dateString!=nil && ![dateString isEqualToString:@"null"] && dateString!=(id)[NSNull null]){
     // value
}else{
    // null value
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That work. I thought the exception would handle the null properly by itself, but no. Can you please explain why the null ruin my code? I thought the try and catch would be enough.

Comment: you can see your json data in date is null right? and so value is null and null value how can possible convert to date using date formate thats reason to you get error. @kanpot2002

Comment: simple you think you get value in string and convert to int but your string value is null that time you can't convert to int so check null condition to value is null or not. @kanpot2002

Comment: I know that you cannot convert null into NSDate, but the reason I thought it would work is because it is in try{}catch{} statement, which should handle any exceptions. But why does null value exception not handled by the try catch?

Comment: @kanpot2002: You are not writing Java or C++ code, but Objective-C. In Objective-C, exceptions are only used for programming errors. You don't catch exceptions. If there is an exception thrown, it means your code is broken, and you fix your code. Invalid data is usually no programming error, therefore no exception.

Comment: Thank you @gnasher729, and yes I am a Java and C# programmer. It is rather confusing.